# Re-uploading a Git repository to a new remote

Tags: git, repository

I have a local repository that I have uploaded to a remote repository.

All files were uploaded successfully, including the full history of commits.
I then decided to delete that remote repository as I wanted to upload the code to a new remote repository.

I used `git remote remove origin` to disassociate my local repository from the first remote repository.

After I used `git remote add origin <new repo url>` and then `git add -A` and then the usual commit and push, I find that it only uploads recently modified files to the new repository, and not the full set that happened with the first remote repository upload.

My question is how do I reset what git considers has been already uploaded, so that this second remote repository can contain everything from my local repository, as it did with the first remote upload? I am looking for a solution that does not require me to manually amend each of the files that are shown up by typing `git ls-files -v`

I have scoured Stack Overflow and tried all of the following, but each with no success:

`git add . -f` (but this includes all files, including those stipulated to not be included according to .gitignore)

`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged *.*`

`git push origin refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*`

`git update-index --really-refresh` (but this has been reported on other sites to now not work)

Thank you for any pointers you might offer.

Comment: What makes you think the new remote doesn't have everything?  You shouldn't even had the need to do any commit. Just push should have pushed everything to the remote. Did you try to use another name than `origin` for the new remote and `git push remoteName branchName`?

Comment: Hello Gael J. The new remote does not have everything as when I look there, it doesn't have the files. In addition, after using ```git add -A``` and ```git status``` it does not list any files that are staged for the commit and push. I had not yet tried another name other than 'origin', but will do so and I'll report back on whether that worked, or not. Thanks for your suggestion of something to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, an update: I found that renaming the 'origin' to something else did not have the required effect. However `git push -u origin --all` seemed to do what I needed it to.